# Cloud ML: Varying training time taken for the same data

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am using Google Cloud ML to for training jobs. I observe a peculiar behavior in which I observe varying time taken for the training job to complete for the same data. I analyzed the CPU and Memory utilization in the cloud ML console and see very similar utilization in both the cases(7min and 14mins). 
Can anyone let me know what would be the reason for the service to take inconsistent time for the job to complete.
I have the same parameters and data in both the cases and also verified that the time spent in the `PREPARING` phase is pretty much the same in both cases. 
Also would it matter that I schedule simultaneous multiple independent training job on the same project, if so then would like to know the rationale behind it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you record training throughput into summaries? If so, looking at that in TensorBoard might shed a clue on what happens in jobs that take longer.

Comment: Yes. I am using the tensorflow's inbuilt Estimator class which handles the summaries. I did look at them through tensorboard, but not sure if I found any metric that could help in figuring out why certain runs are taking longer than others. If you could point to the exact metric that I should be looking for, that would be very helpful. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add more logging to inspect where the time was spent. You can also inspect training progress using TensorBoard. There's no VM sharing between multiple jobs, so it's unlikely caused by simultaneous jobs.

Also, the running time should be measured from the point when the job enters RUNNING state. Job startup latency varies depending on it's cold or warm start (i.e., we keep the VMs from previous job running for a while).

Comment: I added logging, but what I observe is that even though the job in is `RUNNING` state, the first log from my main method,(this is the first statement in my trainer package), appears much after the job entered the `RUNNING` state. Can you let me know what exactly does the `RUNNING` state imply? Is it that the package has begun execution(which doesn't seem like in this case) or are there any additional steps that are performed in running state before the trainer package is executed?

Comment: RUNNING means the containers for you jobs are entering running state, but the catch is that execution of user code may not be started yet as we execute the launcher script before we execute user code. Can you share the ids for fast and slow jobs together with project number with us via cloudml-feedback@google.com please?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have mailed the job IDs as requested.